# Use of the Blog / Newsletter

Tags: feature-request, site-promotion

Our site has a blog feature which we have never used. The blog point to the main site. Also I read somewhere some sites have a newsletter. Perhaps we can try to have on also.

I think we can automate this process also with the data site queries so might not be much of an overhead for the moderators.

Comment: The newsletter is automatically generated - you can find Buddhism SE's on http://stackexchange.com/newsletters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a question on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/how-are-blogs-created) where the blog feature was first discussed and introduced. In the accepted answer it says:

> Here are some guidelines that I would expect to see from a community wanting a blog:
>
> 1. **Raise the idea on the child meta.**  A community blog needs the involvement of community members.
> 2. **Define the scope and purpose of the blog.**  Is the blog about the site?  Is it about the site's topic?  Is it about the industry around the topic?  Keep in mind the audience of your community and their interests.  Another generic blog about <x> may not be all that interesting.
> 3. **Recruit contributors.**  Who will write entries for the blog?  Starting a blog is a bit like going through the buffet line.  Be realistic - don't let your eyes be bigger than your stomach.  Think seriously about if and how often you will be able to contribute a blog post, including research/prep time.
> 4. **Plan a schedule**.  Given the results of steps #2 and #3, think about a rough idea of a schedule for the blog.  Will there be one post a week, posted Mondays?  Will there be <x> posts on Tuesdays and <y> posts on Fridays?  You don't need to be pushing out posts daily, but I would say at least one post a week.

You've just done the first step. We now need to discuss the scope and see how many people are willing to contribute to a blog (or newsletter).

BTW, I disagree with the 'at least one post a week' mentioned at point 4. I think one every other month (5 per year) is the bare minimum.

Comment: How do we get this started? How do we get the editors? What needs to be done?

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala you need to raise awareness here on meta about this initiative and ask people if they want to contribute. You can start by asking one of the mods to make this post a 'featured' post so it will show up in the 'Featured on Meta' box on the main site and hopefully draw some attention.

Comment: I also found [this article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/), where at the bottom is more info on how to get started.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala You can also look at how other sites have tried to do it, by looking into their 'meta' sites: for example, http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=blog and http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=blog

Comment: Which are good sites to look at?

Comment: On my mobile. I didn't see the links before. Will look at them.

Comment: Other sites also have it. We also need to follow. E.g. http://islam.blogoverflow.com/

Comment: Also some sites have twitter and facebook accounts. We could do something on that front also.

Comment: Lets start with twitter and facebook. Also there is Quora. May be we can look at some integration with it also.

Comment: Also G+ page also would be great.

Comment: Hey, talk talk talk. I read the whole page and there is no talk about a start. How about we drop the antics and start for heavens sake and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

The creation of new site blogs is on hiatus, but that's not to say that the community here shouldn't make plans for what they would want to see in a blog down the line.

There isn't any real proper integration between the blog and Q&A systems. The blogs we do create - and their authors - ultimately suffer as a result of that disconnect. We're looking to fix all this but it's going to take some time, and we feel that it's better to have people wait for a more complete blog experience than to continue to create ill-fated blogs. However, that's not to say that this community shouldn't discuss the idea of a blog or collect volunteers and ideas for posts. It's just a disclaimer that it may be many months before the blog can be created.

Comment: Ping us on this when the infrastructure becomes available.